# Mensagem de erro ao tentar criar um objeto de classe ltraj com o pacote adehabitatLT: "non unique dates for a given burst"

Tags: r

Olá, estou tentando criar um objeto da classe ltraj com o pacote adehabitat LT, mas sempre aparece a mensagem de erro "non unique dates for a given burst".
Segue amostra dos dados e os comandos que estou usando.

```
Myc 
Date    Time    Receiver    Transmitter ID    Sensor.Value Sensor.Unit    Station Name    Longitude   Latitude
2019-04-29  05:31:33    134321  4828    #MB06   28.7       °C             PRN               102          121
2019-04-29  08:52:08    134325  4830    #MB06   4.2         m             MVW               102          178
2019-04-29  08:53:13    134325  4831    #MB02   28.6       °C             MVW               150          178
29-04-2019  09:02:22    134325  4885    #MB04   3.9         m             MVW                531861.22  8013605.37
29-04-2019  09:03:55    134325  4884    #MB04   28.57      °C             MVW                531861.22  8013605.37
29-04-2019  09:06:51    134325  4884    #MB04   28.57      °C             MVW                531861.22  8013605.37
29-04-2019  09:09:01    134325  4884    #MB04   28.57      °C             MVW                531861.22  8013605.37
29-04-2019  09:10:15    134325  4885    #MB04   4.2         m             MVW               531861.22   8013605.37
29-04-2019  09:11:22    134321  4894    #MB03   28.57      °C             PRN               532228.65   8013999.41
29-04-2019  09:14:06    134325  4885    #MB04   4.2         m             MVW               531861.22   8013605.37
29-04-2019  09:15:29    134325  4884    #MB04   28.57      °C             MVW              531861.22    8013605.37

myc<-read.csv("mycbon.csv", header = T, sep=";", dec=",")
da<- as.character(myc$Date)
da<-as.POSIXct(strptime(as.character(myc$Date),"%Y-%m-%d"))
da
id<- as.character(myc$ID)
id
myctraj<- as.ltraj(xy = myc[,c("X", "Y")], date = da, id = myc$ID,  burst  = id ,  typeII  =  TRUE)
myctraj
```

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Em primeiro lugar, os dados tal como estão na pergunta devem ser primeiro processados, estão com as datas em dois formatos diferentes, ymd e dmy.

```
xy <- coordinates(myc[, c("Longitude", "Latitude")])
dttm <- as.POSIXct(paste(myc$Date, myc$Time), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
i <- is.na(dttm)
dttm[i] <- as.POSIXct(paste(myc$Date[i], myc$Time[i]), format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Depois de resolvido esse erro, é só seguir os exemplos da página de ajuda `help("as.ltraj")`.

### 1º exemplo, `typeII  =  FALSE`

```
myctraj1 <- as.ltraj(xy = xy, id = myc$ID,  typeII  =  FALSE)
myctraj1
plot(myctraj1)
```

### 2º exemplo, `typeII  =  TRUE`

```
myctraj2 <- as.ltraj(xy = xy, date = dttm, id = myc$ID,  typeII  =  TRUE)
myctraj2
plot(myctraj2)
```

---

### Dados

```
myc <-
structure(list(Date = c("2019-04-29", "2019-04-29", 
"2019-04-29", "2019-04-29", "2019-04-29", "2019-04-29", 
"2019-04-29", "2019-04-29", "2019-04-29", "2019-04-29", 
"2019-04-29"), Time = c("05:31:33", "08:52:08", 
"08:53:13", "09:02:22", "09:03:55", "09:06:51", "09:09:01", 
"09:10:15", "09:11:22", "09:14:06", "09:15:29"), 
Receiver = c(134321L, 134325L, 134325L, 134325L, 134325L, 
134325L, 134325L, 134325L, 134321L, 134325L, 134325L), 
Transmitter = c(4828L, 4830L, 4831L, 4885L, 4884L, 4884L, 
4884L, 4885L, 4894L, 4885L, 4884L), ID = c("#MB06", "#MB06", 
"#MB02", "#MB04", "#MB04", "#MB04", "#MB04", "#MB04", "#MB03", 
"#MB04", "#MB04"), Sensor.Value = c(28.7, 4.2, 28.6, 3.9, 
28.57, 28.57, 28.57, 4.2, 28.57, 4.2, 28.57), Sensor.Unit = c("C", 
"m", "C", "m", "C", "C", "C", "m", "C", "m", "C"), 
Station.Name = c("PRN", "MVW", "MVW", "MVW", "MVW", "MVW", 
"MVW", "MVW", "PRN", "MVW", "MVW"), Longitude = c(102, 102, 
150, 531861.22, 531861.22, 531861.22, 531861.22, 531861.22, 
532228.65, 531861.22, 531861.22), Latitude = c(121, 178, 178, 
8013605.37, 8013605.37, 8013605.37, 8013605.37, 8013605.37, 
8013999.41, 8013605.37, 8013605.37)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), 
class = "data.frame")
```